# Spark replace rdd field value by another value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, rdd

I am a Spark newbie.

I can see the content of the first RDD in my elasticsearch database using:

```
print(es_rdd.first())
>>>(u'1', {u'name': u'john'})
```

I can also get the needed value for my Dstream using:

```
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list":brokers})
name=kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
name.pprint()
>>>>robert
```

I intend to replace the rdd "name": "john" with "robert" and then insert the new rdd in elasticsearch with saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile()

How can I do this?
Is there way to map "robert" into a new rdd? Something like..

```
new_rdd=es_rdd.map(lambda item: {item[0]:name})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can replace a part of RDD with another RDD according to a list of indices. For example, replace elements in a (RDD) from 1,2,3,4 to 2,3,4,4.

```
a = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
repVals = sc.parallelize([2,3,4])
idx = sc.parallelize([0,1,2]) . # idx has the same number of values with repVals

a = a.zipWithIndex()
ref = idx.zip(repVals).collectAsMap() # create a dictionary of format {idex:repValue}

anew = a.map(lambda x:ref[x[1]] if x[1] in ref else x[0])
anew.collect()
```

The result shows [2,3,4,4]